# How can I customize this if statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to show "not selected" when `@user.user_profile.prefecture.name if !@user.user_profile.prefecture.blank?` was blank.

How can I customize this code?

### controller

```
@user.profile.prefecture.name if !@user.profile.prefecture.blank?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the ternary operator, which is slightly verbose:

```
@user.profile.prefecture.blank? ? "Not selected" : @user.profile.prefecture.name
```

Or, if `prefecture` is actually nil/not-nil, get rid of the `blank?`:

```
@user.profile.prefecture ? @user.profile.prefecture.name : "Not selected"
```

Finally, you could get slightly more fancy with `try` and `||`, which most proficient Ruby developers will find quite readable:

```
@user.profile.prefecture.try(:name) || "Not selected"
```

Comment: This is what exactly I wanted

Answer (score 2):

Like this

```
if @user.profile.prefecture.blank?
  'not selected'
else
  @user.profile.prefecture.name
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Updated:

1- An object is blank if it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string

2- Unless statement code to execute unless condition false

Answer:

"Not selected" unless !@user.profile.prefecture.blank?

Explain: @user.profile.prefecture.blank? will return true everytime that @user.profile.prefecture it’s false, empty, or a whitespace string for what the negation operator transforms that into false so the unless code section can be executed.

This approach it's very 'Ruby' to me and should be pretty easy to understand.

Comment: This doesn't work. It evaluates to `"Not selected"` or `nil`, where the question wants  `@user.profile.prefecture.name` or `"Not selected"`.

Comment: Sorry meagar but this "Not selected" unless @user.profile.prefecture.blank? works everytime that @user.profile.prefecture.blank? returns nil originaly I left the ! sign because of the copy paste you've could edited that. 

code unless conditional - Executes code if conditional is false.

Comment: So why don't you edit your own post and make sure nobody in the future has to necessarily read through the comments to figure that out?

Comment: its edited 7 hours ago from now, why you fight Anthon? Meagar at least had a technical point.

Comment: thnx Anthon ist edited as the original was (it was correct) and explained so people don't know as previous people did don't think it's wrong and don't lead to confusion.